# outlook redemption

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

I was evaluating the outlook redemption for conversion of .eml to .msg file and subsequently purchase of the software.

what I found was it uses current user login to connect to outlook and convert a .eml file to .msg.

but I would like to know is that if we deploy this on the server we would use a service account for the conversion.

now the question is whether this service account that is used to perform the .eml to .msg conversion is required to have valid email id on the exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
LogonExchangeMailbox(User, ServerName) or
LogonPstStore(Path, Format, DisplayName, Password, Encryption)
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdosession.htm

Comment: Hello Roeland,Thanks for the response,the question is do we need a valid email id for service account on the exchange server

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you do not need to log in to convert an EML file to MSG: call RDOSession.CreateMessageFroMMsgFIle (returns RDOMail object), call RDOMail.IMport(..., olRfc822) to import the EML file, then RDOMail.Save.